# How do I draw on drawingArea widget using Cairo?

Tags: haskell, gtk, cairo

I have this little project where I try to use gi-gtk to draw on a window.

https://github.com/bigos/cairo-example/blob/b9480dc63d6fff3bc195d35c7422f193fc8ae7d4/src/Main.hs

I have figured out how to make gi-gtk work with Cairo.

https://github.com/haskell-gi/haskell-gi/wiki/Using-Cairo-with-haskell-gi-generated-bindings

But I have a problem with obtaining cairo context. In the following code I have two events. The first event works fine. But I can't figure out how to get the cairo context needed for drawing on canves when I listen to key presses on window object.

```
  win <- Gtk.windowNew WindowTypeToplevel
  canvas <- Gtk.drawingAreaNew
  Gtk.containerAdd win canvas

  _ <- Gtk.onWidgetDraw canvas $ \context ->
    renderWithContext context (updateCanvas canvas) >> pure True

  _ <- Gtk.onWidgetKeyPressEvent win $ \x -> do
    vvv <- Gdk.getEventKeyKeyval x
    -- How do I draw on canvas here?
    (putStrLn ("You have pressed key code " ++  (show vvv))) >> pure True
```

Comment: It’s been a while since I programmed gtk. It might be that you can only drwa from `onWidgetDraw`, and you use [Gtk.widgetQueueDraw](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-queue-draw) on the widget to trigger the drawing. This makes sense because the UI always has to be able to redraw the window, so whatever you would draw in `onWidgetKeyPressEvent`, if you could, would get lost when the user resizes the window or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, you can't. You will not have access to the drawing context outside of the `onWidgetDraw` callback.
What you can (and should) do is to use a global state to allow your `onWidgetDraw` callback to draw different things depending on what happens. For example, if you want to draw some text when the user press the right arrow:

- In the `onWidgetKeyPressEvent` callback, set a value in your global state when the user presses the selected key
- In the `onWidgetDraw` callback, use that value to determine if you have to draw the text or not.
  Ideally, you'd try to fit your state in a State Monad or something similar - however, in this specific case, Gtk doesn't allow injecting Monadic state itself, so this is not directly possible. You have to resort to `IORef`s, `TVar`s or any equivalent.
  Good luck! :)

Comment: I'm not saying you are wrong, but I have found the following functions which might add something to your answer https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gi-gtk-3.0.22/docs/GI-Gtk-Functions.html#g:16    https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gi-gtk-3.0.22/docs/GI-Gtk-Functions.html#g:17

Comment: Drawing events are triggered only when I expose or resize window. I need to figure out how to trigger drawing event on a keypress

Comment: In my key press event I can say Gtk.widgetQueueDraw canvas and force calling redraw of the widget. Not I need to figure out the global state.

Comment: [Documentation for C](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-draw) please note that `user_data` which can be a pointer to anywhere, where you can store different values

Comment: +1. This is right. `queue_draw` (or `Gtk.widgetQueueDraw`) is also the right thing to use. I'm not familiar with Haskell, but in other languages, a typical solution might be using a global variable to handle state.